# iOS Localisation I need to give Haitian Creole language support, how can I give

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, creole

I need to give Haitian Creole language support in iOS

Sample text
"Tanpri kenbe kote sou pou karakteristik SOS. Pou pèmèt kote ou ye a, tape Anviwònman > kote."

I can not find it in iOS language list,
neither Haitian nor creole
https://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

can I give default support tot his language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple documentation and product should always be your first source.

Go to `Your Project > Info > Localizations > + > More languages > Haitian Creole`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-support-for-languages-and-regions